# How can I show groups in membership report columns?

Tags: civireport, groups, custom-templates

I've got the request to display (certain) groups in the membership detail report. A lot has been written over time about customizing reports, and I'm not sure what info is up-to-date. This looks good:
https://alastaira.wordpress.com/2011/03/17/civicrm-creating-a-custom-report/

I think roughly, I would need to

- set up the paths for custom templates and php files at setting/path
- create a custom template with just a single {include file="CRM/Report/Form.tpl"}
- create a custom php file copied from CRM/Report/Form/Member/Detail.php
- register both using Administer –> CiviReport –> Manage Templates
- in the php file, append stuff to _columns and from()

is that correct ? Has anyone already done something like this for groups .. ?

Comment: as Lobo points out below, this is the legacy way of doing it.

Comment: having said that, I did it just as described, and it was fairly easy :-)

Comment: having said that, I created an extension to do this later, and it was fairly easy too :-)

Answer (score 4):

The current correct way to create a custom report is to use an extension, rather than the manual process linked to in the question.

Updated documentation for creating a report extension is found here:

https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/civix/#generate-report

The link in Donald Lobo's answer is now broken, but an old version of the document is still available here:

https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC46/Create+a+Report-Template+Extension

Answer (score 3):

A better approach might be to use an extension rather than the above. Documentation for report extensions here:

http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Create+a+Report-Template+Extension

You might be able to borrow some code from other reports which show the groups a contact belongs to (not sure if any report does so)

Comment: ew, there you go, I already used the 'legacy' way of creating a report :-/ I dont think any of the default reports show groups for contacts.